# How Remote Development of C++ works in Netbeans?

Tags: c++, netbeans

Hi we want to use remote development features of netbeans but while trying out on our setup its very slow. I want to understand its feasibility of integrating our build environment with netbeans.

Our setup would be normally: 
1. Windows 7 Professional 64bit where we install netbeans 
2. RHEL 5.5 64bit linux where we have tools and sources

Normally we directly connect to that machine through PuTTY and use VIM to edit sources and gmake to compile and build projects. Now when I created the "New Remote Project with existing sources" and try to use it It took more time to load the project.

So Can anybody tell me how actually this remote compilation works?? 
Because we have some GBs of sources here on linux box and I want to know is it possible for smooth development with this big data??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple steps. Read this [tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/remotedev-tutorial.html). You just need a SSH-server on your Linux.

The process is easy, your Netbeans connects to the SSH-server and searches for compilation tools then uses them to build your projects.

The second issue is creating a shared folder that your Windows and Linux able to access to it. I suggest you first create a shared folder on your Windows and use Samba client on your Linux.